# Getting first Span from Spannable

Tags: android, html, parsing

I'm trying to parse some HTML code and retrieve the contents of an img tag. I've used the following
code to do so:

```
Spanned img = Html.fromHtml(sourceText);
```

When I start to debug and view the contents of the Spanned img object, I can see that mSpans contains one ImageSpan, this ImageSpans source is the correct url. I'm having extreme difficulty retrieving the source though. The documentation is pretty unclear about retrieving an ImageSpan from a Spanned object. I've tried this method:

```
ImageSpan[] spans = img.getSpans(0, img.length(), ImageSpan.class);
```

But that just returns an empty array.

So to be clear: I want to retrieve the ImageSpan in the Spanned object.

Comment: question is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've edited my original post. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: can you give me the sourcetext which contains imagespan so that I can check.

Comment: @TimKranen I am using the same code for image with text...But it does not work on the MArshmallow and above API..could u please help me on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
public ImageSpan[] getImageSpans(Spanned original, Class<ImageSpan> sourceType) {
    SpannableStringBuilder result = new SpannableStringBuilder(original);
    ImageSpan[] spans = result.getSpans(0, result.length(), sourceType);

    return spans;
}
```

**How to use**

```
ImageSpan[] spans  = getImageSpans(Html.fromHtml("sourceText"), ImageSpan.class);
```

Comment: @BirajZalavadiaI am using the same code for image with text...But it does not work on the MArshmallow and above API..could u please help me on it